# Recursive Manager - Oracle 10g x 11g

Tags: oracle-10g, recursive

We have a problem adapting a recursive SQL from **11g** to **10g**.

**Oracle 11g** Query ( *Working as expected* )

```
WITH ADRECURSIVEUSERLEADER (CDLEADER,CDUSER,NMUSER,FGUSERENABLED)
AS
(
    SELECT US.CDLEADER AS CDLEADER
          ,US.CDUSER AS CDUSER
          ,US.NMUSER
          ,US.FGUSERENABLED
      FROM ADUSER US
     WHERE 1 = 1
     UNION ALL
    SELECT RS.CDLEADER
          ,US.CDUSER
          ,US.NMUSER
          ,US.FGUSERENABLED
      FROM ADRECURSIVEUSERLEADER RS
           INNER JOIN ADUSER US 
               ON RS.CDUSER = US.CDLEADER
     WHERE 1 = 1
)
SELECT * 
  FROM ADRECURSIVEUSERLEADER T
 WHERE 1 = 1;
```

---

**Oracle 10g** Query ( *What we are trying* )

```
WITH ADRECURSIVEUSERLEADER 
AS
(
    SELECT US.CDLEADER AS CDLEADER
          ,US.CDUSER AS CDUSER
          ,US.NMUSER
          ,US.FGUSERENABLED
      FROM ADUSER US
     START WITH US.CDLEADER IS NULL         -- parent
   CONNECT BY PRIOR US.CDUSER = US.CDLEADER -- child / parent
)
SELECT * 
  FROM ADRECURSIVEUSERLEADER T
 WHERE 1 = 1;
```

---

**What is the problem?**

We have the following leader structure:

- User code (CDUSER)    **5** is the **CEO**
- User code (CDUSER)   **21** is the **Manager**   (*Leaded by* **5**)
- User code (CDUSER)  **937** is the **Leader**    (*Leaded by* **21**)
- User code (CDUSER) **1276** is the **Developer** (*Leaded by* **937**)

If I search for a leader on **10g** and **11g** :

```
AND T.CDLEADER = 21
```

**11g** shows me two records:

- One for  **937** ( *Leader* )
- One for **1276** ( *Developer* )

**10g** shows me only one record:

- One for  **937** ( *Leader* )

---

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8200a/1/0)

**DDL for Oracle**:

```
CREATE TABLE ADUSER (CDUSER          NUMBER(10)
                    ,CDLEADER        NUMBER(10)
                    ,FGUSERENABLED   NUMBER(2)
                    ,NMUSER          VARCHAR2(255) );

INSERT INTO ADUSER VALUES (   5, NULL, 1, 'CEO Name');
INSERT INTO ADUSER VALUES (  21,    5, 1, 'Manager Name');
INSERT INTO ADUSER VALUES ( 937,   21, 1, 'Leader Name');
INSERT INTO ADUSER VALUES (1276,  937, 1, 'Developer Name');
```

---

**What I need?**

I need to know **everyone under the leader** I search and the filter must me apllied on the (ADRECURSIVEUSERLEADER T) because it's going to be a view . Is that possible on Oracle 10g?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: [Oracle Forum](https://community.oracle.com/message/13243416#13243416)

```
WITH ADRECURSIVEUSERLEADER
   AS
   (
       SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT US.CDLEADER AS CDLEADER
             ,US.CDUSER AS CDUSER
             ,US.NMUSER
             ,US.FGUSERENABLED
         FROM ADUSER US
      CONNECT BY PRIOR US.CDUSER = US.CDLEADER -- child / parent
   )
   SELECT *
     FROM ADRECURSIVEUSERLEADER T
    WHERE 1 = 1 order by  cdleader, cduser;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the people "under" `CDLEADER = 21`, then why do use `START WITH US.CDLEADER IS NULL` in your `CONNECT BY`? Just simply use `START WITH US.CDLEADER = 21`:

```
WITH ADRECURSIVEUSERLEADER 
AS
(
    SELECT US.CDLEADER AS CDLEADER
          ,US.CDUSER AS CDUSER
          ,US.NMUSER
          ,US.FGUSERENABLED
      FROM ADUSER US
     START WITH US.CDLEADER = 21         -- parent
   CONNECT BY PRIOR US.CDUSER = US.CDLEADER -- child / parent
)
SELECT * 
  FROM ADRECURSIVEUSERLEADER T
 WHERE 1 = 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8200a/9/0)

Comment: Hello Balazs Papp, Thanks for the answer, that is something we will consider. The only problem for us, is that we are trying to use the SQL as View and then filter the view, due to our application must support other databases. Do you have any other ideas? Is that possible on Oracle 10g?